# Is the function onto?

Tags: functions

Is the function is bijective?

$$F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R;\quad 
F(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) $$

I made the graph of this function.and found that it cuts x axis on 3 points.....But I am really very unsure about how to find onto as  my concept about onto is not yet clear.

Comment: Hint: Use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: $F(x)$ is continuous and is less than $x$ for large negative $x$ and is more than $x$ for large positive $x$.  What do you think?

Comment: Is the function bijective?  No.  Is the function onto?  Yes.  Your question in the body is different than the question in the title.  As for proving that it is surjective (onto) you can use other theorems, namely that this function is continuous (as all polynomials are) and as $x$ tends to infinity the function tends to infinity and as $x$ tends to negative infinity the function tends to negative infinity.  You can then use something like Rolle's theorem to conclude that it actually passes each output along the way.

Comment: As for why the function is not bijective,  consider $F(1),F(2)$ and $F(3)$.  For a function to be bijective (and injective in particular, i.e. one-to-one) what must be true about $F(a)$ and $F(b)$ when $a\neq b$?

Comment: "and found that it cuts x axis on 3 points"  Well, that proves it is not injective, doesn't it?  $f(1) = f(2)=f(3) = 0$ but $1\ne 2$ and $2\ne 3$ and $1\ne 3$.

Comment: "But I am really very unsure about how to find onto".  Who cares if it is onto?  It is not injective so it is not bijective whether it is onto or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is the function is bijective?"

That would mean it has to be *BOTH* injective and surjective.

"I made the graph of this function.and found that it cuts x axis on 3 points"

So it is NOT injective.  So it is not *BOTH* injective and surjective.  So it is not bijective.  So we are done.  Let's go home and eat lunch.

"But I am really very unsure about how to find onto"

What are you still doing here?  I told you to go home and eat lunch.  It doesn't matter if it is onto (surjective) or not.  Since it is *NOT* injective (1 to 1) and can't be bijective whether it is surjective or not.

Well, you are curious and I can't blame you for that.

And if someone asked you "Is this function onto" that would be fair.

"Onto" means that for any possible $v \in \mathbb R$ there is at least one $x$ so that $f(x) = v$.

You should have seen by graphing that the the function increases as $x$ is large positive, and decreases as $x$ is large negative.  So intuitively it seems like it ought to cover ever possible real value.

So it ought to be surjective.

But that's not a proof.  A proof would be that $f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) = v$ will always have at least one solution.

Case 1: $v = 0$ then $x = 1, 2$ or $3$ would yield that $f(x) = 0$.

Case 2: $v > 0$.  Then $w = \sqrt[3]{v} + 3 > 3 > 0$.  $f(w) = (w-1)(w-2)(x-3) = (\sqrt[3] v+ 2) (\sqrt[3] v+ 1) (\sqrt[3] v0) > \sqrt[3]{v}\sqrt[3]{v}\sqrt[3]{v} = v$.  So $f(0) =-6 < v$ and $f(w)  >v > f(0)$.  And as $f$ is continuous, by the intermediate value theorem there must be an $x; 0 < x < w$ so that $f(x) = v$.

Case 3: $v < 0$ then Then $w = \sqrt[3]{v}< 0$.  And $f(w) = (w-1)(w-2)(w-3) < w*w*w = w^3 = v < 0$.  And $f(1) = 0 > v > f(w)$.  And as $f$ is continuous, by the intermediate value theorem there must be an $x; w < x < 1$ so that $f(x) = v$.

Basically:

The intuition for the intermediate value theorem is that if $f(x_0) < v$--  And since $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = \infty$ we can always find an $x_0$ so that $f(x_0) < v$--  and if $f(x_1) > 0$-- And since $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ we can always find an $x_1$ so that $f(x_1) > v$-- then somewhere between $x_0$ and $x_1$ the function $f$ went for $< v$ to $> v$.  ANd as the $f$ is continuous, it couldn't just "jump" from less than $v$ and greater than $v$ without passing *through* $v$ along the way.  So there must be some value of $x$ between $x_0$ and $x_1$ so that $f(x) = v$.

Comment: Oh, typos.  Life would be so boring without them....

Comment: Yeah! Got it.well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try:

1) injective: It is not

$f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=0$, I.e. $x_1\not= x_2 \not=x_3$ are mapped onto $0.$

2) surjective: Yes.

$f(x) =x^3 +ax^2 +bx + c$, $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}.$

$x^3$ is the leading term.

Let

1)$x \rightarrow +\infty$ $ f(x)  \rightarrow +\infty$.

2) $x \rightarrow -\infty$ $f(x) \rightarrow -\infty$.

Choose any $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a,b$ be such that  $f(a) \lt y \lt f(b)$ ( Property 1),2),).

$f$ is continuos on $[a,b]$ , there is a $x \in [a,b],$ with

$f(x) = y$ (Intermediate value theorem),

hence surjective.

Comment: Now it's very clear